# How to wait for request to be finished with axios-mock-adapter like it's possible with moxios?

Tags: jasmine, moxios, axios-mock-adapter

I try to test a rendering of some content after fetching it from server.
I use `Vue Test Utils` but this is irrelevant.

In the `created` hook of the component the ajax call is made with `axios`. I register the `axios-mock-adapter` response and 'render' the component, the call is made and everything works fine but i have to use the `moxios` lib only to wait for request to be finished.

```
it('displays metrics', (done) => {

  this.mock.onGet('/pl/metrics').reply((config) => {
    let value = 0
    if (config.params.start == '2020-01-26') {
      value = 80
    }
    if (config.params.start == '2020-01-28') {
      value = 100
    }
    return [200, {
      metrics: [
        {
          key: "i18n-key",
          type: "count",
          value: value
        }
      ]
    }]
  })
  .onAny().reply(404)

  let wrapper = mount(Dashboard)

  moxios.wait(function() {
    let text = wrapper.text()
    expect(text).toContain('80')
    expect(text).toContain('100')
    expect(text).toContain('+20')
    done()
  })
})
```

Is it possible to get rid of `moxios` and achieve the same with `axios-mock-adapter` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can implement your own `flushPromises` method with async/ await:

```js
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))

it('displays metrics', async () => {
  this.mock.onGet('/pl/metrics').reply((config) => {
    // ..
  }).onAny().reply(404)

  let wrapper = mount(Dashboard)

  await flushPromises()

  expect(text).toContain('80')
})
```

Or use `done` and `setTimeout`:

```js
it('displays metrics', (done) => {
  this.mock.onGet('/pl/metrics').reply((config) => {
    // ..
  }).onAny().reply(404)

  let wrapper = mount(Dashboard)

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(text).toContain('80')
    done()
  })
})
```

`moxiois.wait` simply [schedules a callback with `setTimeout`](https://github.com/axios/moxios/blob/v0.4.0/index.js#L385). This works because a task scheduled by setTimeout always runs after the microtask queue, like promise callbacks, is emptied.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edd! I will try it out as soon as possible! :)